# What is the proper way to stop hiveserver2?

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hive, redhat

I've installed hive 0.14 on top of hadoop 2.6.0.

The setup mainly involved just extracting the tar.bin file.

I followed this guide to do the setup.

http://www.ishaanguliani.com/content/hive-0140-setup-ubuntu

I start hiveserver2 with a command line:

```
( $HIVE_HOME/bin/hiveserver2 &> hiveserver.log & )
```

Now, I am wondering what is the proper to stop hiveserver2. I can kill it but I doubt that provides a graceful exit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

write a small shell script to find hiveserver2 process and stop it. I used below shell script to stop hiveserver2 and hive metastore process. Hope this helps.

```
hive2_pid=`pgrep -f org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2`

    if [[ -n "$hive2_pid" ]]
    then
        echo "Found hivesevrer2 PID-- "$hive2_pid
        kill $hive2_pid
        # if process is still around, use kill -9
        if ps -p $hive2_pid > /dev/null ; then
            echo "Initial kill failed, killing with -9 "
            kill -9 $hive2_pid
        fi
    echo "Hive server2 stopped successfully"
    else
        echo "Hiveserver2 process not found , HIveserver2 is not running !!!"
    fi

    meta_pid=`pgrep -f org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore`

    if [[ -n "$meta_pid" ]]
    then
        echo "Found hivesevrer2 PID-- "$meta_pid
        kill $meta_pid
        # if process is still around, use kill -9
        if ps -p $meta_pid > /dev/null ; then
            echo "Initial kill failed, killing with -9 "
            kill -9 $meta_pid
        fi
    echo "Hive metastore stopped successfully"
    else
        echo "Hive metastore process not found , Hive metastore is not running !!!"
    fi
```

Comment: so hiveserver2 just needs to be killed?

Comment: yes. This works for me. ASF Hive has a Jira to create stop script for hiveserver2. Hopefully you will see stop hiveserver soon.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sudo service hive-server2 stop
```

refer this link :  http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_8.html

Comment: Its not a cloudera setup. Its a vanilla install. That command you supplied returns: `hive-server2: unrecognized service`

Comment: Then you must find a way to **define a Linux "service"** all by yourself -- probably depends on the distro your are using, I'm only familiar with RedHat / CentOS and `chkconfig`

Comment: Let's assume we know how to define it as a redhat service, I believe the command necessary to perform the actual `stop` is still necessary in the definition.